# is trivial walk closed or open in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Pretty much the title, a walk is said to be closed if the starting and ending vertex is same for the walk. If we have a graph consisting of just 1 vertex 'A' then the starting vertex would be 'A' and ending vertex would be 'A' hence we would have a closed walk

Basically, according to me trivial walk is a closed walk, is that correct?

Comment: What's (the definition of) a trivial walk?

Comment: A trivial walk is a walk that has length zero @AdamRubinson

Answer (score 1):

Graph theory terminology ranges all over the place, so different authors of graph theory textbooks may give different answers.

However, in references I can find that give a definition of a closed walk that goes beyond merely saying "A walk with ending vertex equal to its starting vertex," there is a requirement that the walk be nontrivial; that is, a closed walk is a nontrivial walk (a walk containing at least one edge) with ending vertex identical to its starting vertex.  In this light a trivial walk is neither open nor closed.  We can say the set of closed walks for a graph $G$ is a subset of the set of nontrivial walks for $G$.

But many textbooks do define a closed walk simply as a walk with ending vertex equaling its starting vertex, so that a trivial walk is closed.  I do not see a problem with this idea, and prefer it for one simple reason:  there is also the idea of a trivial circuit.  A **trivial circuit** is a circuit consisting of a single vertex and no edge.  But since a circuit is by definition a closed trail (i.e. a closed walk without repeated edges), and both a trivial walk and a trivial circuit consist of a single vertex, it stands to reason that a trivial walk is identical to a trivial circuit, and therefore a trivial walk is closed.